# SweetAlert2 GET https://xxx.xxx.xx net: :ERR_ABORTED 404 Javascript

Tags: javascript, github, get, sweetalert2, github-pages

Tengo un repositorio en mi github el cual es una webapp para registrar una lista de turnos al completar un formulario. Utilizo Sweetalert2 para que al completar y pulsar el boton de "agregar" me aparezca un ventana popup notificando que el registro ha sido exitoso. El problema es que al correr el codigo en mi visual studio code con LiverServer de manera local en mi pc todo anda perfecto, pero al cargarlo en github y realizar una github Page para compartirlo, al pulsar el boton "agregar" no sucede nada, no se carga la lista y no aparece el popup de Sweetalert2.

Entiendo que el error es referido a que no encuentra el archivo _destroy.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al cargar los datos y pulsar "Asignar Turno" me aparece esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo en cuestión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la ruta que esta buscando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no entiendo es porque no lo encuentra si esta en la misma ruta que este archivo update.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se puede ver ambos archivos están dentro de la misma carpeta y misma ruta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Registro de Turnos</title>
  <!-- Enlace CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- Enlace CSS de Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Solicite su Turno</h1>
    <form id="formulario">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="apellido" class="form-label">Apellido</label>
          <input type="text" id="apellido" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="edad" class="form-label">Edad</label>
          <input type="number" id="edad" class="form-control" min="0" max="150" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="dia" class="form-label">Día</label>
          <input type="date" id="dia" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="hora" class="form-label">Hora</label>
          <input type="time" id="hora" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Asignar Turno</button>
    </form>
    <div id="ListaTurnos" class="mt-5">
       <h1 class="text-center">Lista de Turnos</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="turnos" class="mt-5"></div>
    <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
          <th scope="col">Edad</th>
          <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
          <th scope="col">Hora</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="turnero">
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
   <!-- Línea de código de jQuery de Bootstrap -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Enlace JavaScript de Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Enlace JavaScript de SweetAlert2 -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.10/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script> 
  <!-- Vinculación con archivo Javascript-->
  <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el main.js

```js
import Swal from './node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.js'

// Creo un objeto para manejar el almacenamiento en el local storage.
const storage = {
  save: (key, value) => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value)),
  get: (key) => {
  const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
  return value ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
  },
  remove: (key) => localStorage.removeItem(key),
  clear: () => localStorage.clear(),
  };
  
  // Array para almacenar los datos de los pacientes.
  let pacientes = [];
  
  // Función para guardar los datos de los pacientes en el Storage.
  function guardarPacientes() {
  storage.save('pacientes', pacientes);
  }
  
  // Función para recuperar los datos de los pacientes del Storage.
  function recuperarPacientes() {
  const pacientesGuardados = storage.get('pacientes');
  if (pacientesGuardados) {
  pacientes = pacientesGuardados;
  }
  }

  // Array para almacenar los datos de los turnos.
  let turnos = [];
  
  // Función para mostrar la lista de turnos en el HTML.
  function mostrarListaTurnos() {
    let listaTurnos = document.getElementById('turnero');
    listaTurnos.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < turnos.length; i+=1) {
      let pacienteNombre = turnos[i].pacienteNombre;
      let pacienteApellido = turnos[i].pacienteApellido;
      let edad = turnos[i].edad;
      let dia = turnos[i].dia;
      let hora = turnos[i].hora;
      let tr = document.createElement('tr');
      let th = document.createElement('th');
      th.setAttribute('scope', 'row');
      th.innerHTML = `${i+1}`;
      let tN = document.createElement('td');
      let tA = document.createElement('td');
      let tE = document.createElement('td');
      let tD = document.createElement('td');
      let tH = document.createElement('td');
      tN.innerHTML = `${pacienteNombre}`;
      tA.innerHTML = `${pacienteApellido}`;
      tE.innerHTML = `${edad}`;
      tD.innerHTML = `${dia}`;
      tH.innerHTML = `${hora}`; 
      tr.innerHTML = th.outerHTML + tN.outerHTML + tA.outerHTML + tE.outerHTML + tD.outerHTML + tH.outerHTML;
      listaTurnos.appendChild(tr);
    }
  }
  
  // Función para mostrar una notificación al paciente al asignar turno.
  function mostrarNotificacion() {
  Swal.fire({
        title: "Turno guardado",
        text: "El turno ha sido guardado exitosamente",
        icon: "success",
        confirmButtonText: "Aceptar"
      });
    }

  // Función para procesar el formulario cuando el paciente ingresa sus datos.
  function procesarFormulario(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      // Variables para obtener los valores ingresados por el usuario en el formulario.
      const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
      const apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
      const edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
      const dia = document.getElementById('dia').value;
      const hora = document.getElementById('hora').value;
      
      // Valido los datos.
      if (!nombre || !apellido || !edad || !dia || !hora) {
      alert('Por favor complete los campos');
      return;
      }
      
      // Agrego el paciente al array y lo guardo en el Storage.
      pacientes.push({ nombre, apellido, edad, dia, hora });
      guardarPacientes();

      // Muestro la notificación del turno guardado con éxito.
      mostrarNotificacion();

      // Asigno el turno al paciente y lo agrego a la lista de turnos.
      const pacienteNombre = `${nombre}`;
      const pacienteApellido = `${apellido}`;
      turnos.push({ pacienteNombre, pacienteApellido, edad, dia, hora });
      mostrarListaTurnos();
      
      // Limpio el formulario.
      document.getElementById('nombre').value = '';
      document.getElementById('apellido').value = '';
      document.getElementById('edad').value = '';
      document.getElementById('dia').value = '';
      document.getElementById('hora').value = '';
}

  // Función para inicializar la aplicación.
  function inicializar() {
  recuperarPacientes();
  mostrarListaTurnos();
  document.getElementById('formulario').addEventListener('submit', procesarFormulario);
  }
  
  // Llamo a la función para inicializar la aplicación.
  inicializar();
```

Necesito corregir este error, ya he instalado otras librerías y me genera el mismo problema, he proba actualizando la misma librerías con npm y no logro dar con la solución.

dejo la pagina de Github Page https://mikhail-balari.github.io/Shift-List/ por si alguien quiere probarlo.

Dejo el repositorio con todo el codigo: https://github.com/Mikhail-Balari/Shift-List

Agradezco la ayuda, ya que soy iniciante en esto. Saludos.!

Comment: Podrías probar quitando el guion bajo del nombre

Comment: Hola @Yussef gracias por tu respuesta. Pero al quitarle el guion bajo, todos los demás archivos que utilicen o importen el archivo _destroy.js no dejarían de funcionar? tengo que ver que archivo lo utiliza, es decir ver archivo por archivo y modificar ahí mismo la ruta también, la ruta de cada uno de esos o no? ya que si lo utilizan al cambiar el nombre del archivo quitando el guion bajo, cambiaria la ruta de importación.

Comment: Es una prueba solamente. Tu archivo está donde debe estar, los otros archivos que están en la misma carpeta no tienen problema ¿Cual parece ser la única diferencia? El guion bajo es lo primero que se me ocurre, y es que hay sistemas de ficheros y servidores web que solo funcionan con alfanuméricos (no digo que este sea el caso), pero obviamente cuando uno cae en un problema se tienen que probar cosas. Yo te recomiendo probar quitándolo y pruebas a ver que pasa. Pero lo pruebas en un solo lado, porque quizás ni es eso.